# I have problem web scraping image; when I try my code, it just says []

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

This is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r = requests.get('https://www.reddit.com/r/memes/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,'html.parser')
post = soup.find_all('img',attr={'alt:Post image'})
```

The output is `[]`, but I don't know why.

Comment: Because your attr argument isn't a dictionary, it's a set.

Answer (score 0):

As @jonrsharpe pointed out in the comments, you're passing a set as the target attribute rather than a dictionary. Simply remove the colon from inside of the string to set the key and value for the dict:

`post = soup.find_all('img',attr={'alt':'Post image'})`

after that, you can use `img[src]` to get the src link, open the link with a module like urllib2 and download the contents however you please.

Hope this helped

Comment: Tried this, the output was still [].